# How to market a stakepool?

Tags: stake-pool, marketing

Besides:

- Running a zero percent margin pool
- Offering a bonus of 1000 Ada for a stake of 1 million
- Starting a podcast
- Advertising on Adapools.org using coinzilla
- NFT giveaways

What other mechanisms are possible to market a stakepool?

Comment: I'm not sure if non-technical and open questions are a good fit for Stack Exchange. There isn't a definitive answer to this.

Comment: I agree with Edd. Better place to discuss open questions like this is forum.cardano.org

Comment: Sounds good, I’ll close it. The answers were helpful though, I appreciate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the open ended nature. Will submit it on the Cardano forum.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick brainstorm.

**Web Presence**

- Create a Website
  - You should have your own URL
  - Get a basic knowledge of SEO and follow the rules.
- Dedicated Twitter account and follow and comment on everything ADA/Cardano
- Start a dedicated YouTube account and start creating content geared toward your target market. Could be how-to videos, current events, price action talk, interviews, reviews of catalyst proposals and funded projects, developer stuff, education...
- Other social media accounts could include TicTok, Instagram, Facebook, Twitch, etc.
- Answer and Ask questions on stack exchange.
- Create a Discord for your delegators, be available and quick to communicate.
- Do lottery's, giveaways, rewards, raffles, NFTs, Merch, etc.
- Collaborate with an artist to start making NFTs published by your brand.
- Paying for advertising would come after all this stuff. You need to have something for people to see when they start looking into your pool.
- Be yourself. You are unique and you have something to offer that no-one else does.

**Real Life**

- Get some Cardano branded stuff and wear it.
- Become active in your region. Start/join meet-up groups. Talk to people about Cardano.
- Get some gear with your own stake pool brand on it and wear it. Give it to friends and family.
- Give ADA, Native Tokens, NFTs as gifts to friends and family.
- Attend conferences.

Answer (score 2):

You have to know your target group or at least try to reach your target group.

There are users who try to

- maximize their returns from staking (best pool settings)
- improve decentralization (any small pool)
- support certain projects or projects in their area (selected projects, locations, ...)

If you try to reach users who want to maximize their staking return, your listed incentives are good. However, for small pools it will be challenging to be seen, as there are many large pools who already offer zero margin while providing a high block-minting probability. Personally, I believe that the differences between "normal" and "min-maxed" pools are too small to matter. All you do is try to take advantage of filters and search algorithms on certain pool comparison websites.

If you try to reach users who want to support the network by supporting smaller pools and increase decentralization, you just have to "be known". Overall I think that it is difficult to target this group of users specifically. Just try to be an option.

Your best bet is to have something that makes you special. If your pool supports a certain project, you could advertise your pool in this community. If you have a social media following, you can advertise there. You mentioned starting a podcast. To advertise your pool in your podcast, you have to advertise your podcast first. Some users try to support local pools specifically. Use this as an advantage to advertise your pool in a local Cardano community, for example a language specific Cardano subreddit.

The overall best way to get pledges is to become known (duh!). Participate in Cardano communities using a name like "XYZ Pool" and provide good content. Maybe you can use your answers to subtly drop the info that you operate a pool, for example when people ask how much it costs to operate a pool, or when they ask for certain pools in particular. Small events like giveaways are also a great opportunity for acceptable advertisement, as long you select an acceptable platform.